# How do I install custom HTTPS Everywhere rulesets?

Tags: firefox, installation, firefox-extensions

I use the HTTPS Everywhere extension in Firefox and wanted to add some sites that were not covered by the default rulesets.  I followed the [documentation](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/rulesets) to create a custom ruleset, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually install the ruleset in my browser.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the testing procedure in the linked document includes instructions for installing custom rulesets in Firefox.

> You should also manually test your ruleset by placing it in the `HTTPSEverywhereUserRules/` subdirectory in [your Firefox profile directory](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox), and then restarting Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

For simple rules, you can use [testing](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere/rulesets#testing). It persists after restarting.

For complicated rules, you can use [ruleset update channels](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/blob/master/docs/en_US/ruleset-update-channels.md).

Modify `default.rulesets` won't work accoring to [this](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/issues/7635#issuecomment-261753781).

`HTTPSEverywhereUserRules` seems not working anymore accoring to [this](https://github.com/EFForg/https-everywhere/issues/10822).

Comment: The OP was asking how to install the rules. Are you able to expand upon this point?

Comment: Nope. The one who wants to use custom rules in https-everythere will understand what I'm saying. The first two points exactly answer the question.